# How do you open a file with a space in its name?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def openfile():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filename = askopenfilename()
    os.system("open " + filename)
    print(filename)


root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="Choose File", command=openfile)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In short, this seems to work on any file except for files with *a space* in their name.

I've tried executing the code above from my terminal and I get an error due to the space in the name of the file. It seems it has split the file name into two different names, and it has tried to open files that don't even exist (corresponding to those split names).

#### Example of error

> The files /Users/dylanrichards/Desktop/boot and /Users/dylanrichards/Desktop/strap.css do not exist.

The filename in this example was `boot strap.css`.

If anyone can answer this, it would be greatly appreciated...

Here's the screenshot of the output of the command `cat text-opener.py`, where `text-opener.py` is the my Python script that I'm trying to execute.

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVVtL.png)

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues with a space in the file name. A real issue is that you open the file, but don't keep a reference to the file object you create. Once that object is garbage-collected (which will probably be very soon), the file is closed again.

Comment: What's the point of `Tk().withdraw()`?

Comment: @Rawing it makes the Finder window not as big I think

Comment: You are doing it properly. I suspect that you're drawing the wrong conclusion. How do you know it's not opening the file?

Comment: @BryanOakley when i test it on a file with no spaces in its name it works fine, but if i put a space in the name of the same file it doesnt open. Im on Mac so if a file is opening it an icon in the dock tells me it is but it doesnt with files with spaces in the name.

Comment: How can you possibly say "it works fine"? The code you posted does absolutely nothing with the file after it has been opened.

Comment: @BryanOakley just to make sure we are in the same page, i am using python 2.7 and Im running on Mac OS. It IS working fine and the edit you did above does nothing at all.

Comment: Again, how do you KNOW it is working fine? The code opens the file and then does nothing else with it. You say you don't get any errors, so clearly a file with a space will have exactly the same behavior: you open the file and then do nothing with it. (and BTW: my edit was only to add the `tkinter` tag; I didn't change the body of your question)

Comment: @bryanoakley Sorry to waste your time, I've tried executing it from my terminal and I get an error. Due to the space in the name, it has split the file name into two different names and trying to open files that don't even exist. Do you know a solution?

Comment: I do not think it's possible for the code you posted to generate that error. Just to be clear, you're saying _the exact code in this question_ is generating _the exact error_ that you report?

Comment: @bryanoakley well it has. its clear you either don't know the answer because you keep denying it can't happen or you don't want to help, so I'll look somewhere else online.

Comment: I just ran your exact code on OSX, and I create a file with the exact path `/Users/dylanrichards/Desktop/boot strap.css` and the code worked fine. It opened the file and printed the filename. The `open` statement simply cannot generate the error you say it does. Please show the _complete_ error, including the stack trace.

Comment: @dylanr I've run your code and I got no error. I'm also on a Mac. Btw, Bryan Oakley is like the expert in tkinter on SO.

Comment: The code in the screenshot calls `os.system("open " + filename)` but doesn't properly quote the filename, so the command line shell is parsing arguments and splitting on spaces.  Quote the filename.

Comment: @dylanr: you have wasted all of our time. First you said you didn't get an error. Then you claimed this is the exact code. Now we see that the code in your question is _not_ the code you're actually running. There is a _significant_ difference between `open(filename)` and `os.system('open ' + filename)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having that problem because the script you're trying to execute does not contain the same code as the code you originally posted.

In your `text-opener.py` you're trying to open a file as follows:

```
os.system("open filename")
```

According to your example, `filename = "boot strap.css"`. Thus you're trying to execute the following command:

```
os.system("open boot strap.css")
```

which from the terminal would simply translate to a command of the form

```
open boot strap.css
```

and indeed, in that case, I also receive your error. What you need to do is wrap `filename` with quotes, that is

```
os.system("open '"+ filename + "'")
```

or simply use the code you originally posted.

#### In summary

The code you originally posted is not the same code you were trying to execute! You were basically trying to pass different parameters to `open`.

Comment: your solution worked thank god. i appreciate your patience and apolagize for any sarcasm. thanks very much!!!

Comment: @dylanr No problem, at the beginning, it may seem frustrating. But, for next time, I encourage you to make sure twice these little things. And, please, add as many details as necessary specific to your problem.